# Validating javascript onChange event

Tags: javascript, react.js

I'm looking to simplify the below code for validating an onChange event. The `allowedInput` is a regex that is passed (optional) from all the form components.

```
    const validatedOnChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        if (isDisabled) {
            return;
        }
        if (allowedInput) {
            if (allowedInput.test(event.target.value)) {
                onChange({ name, value: event.target.value });
            }
            return;
        }
        onChange({ name, value: event.target.value });
    };
```

This is a common utility method used for all my React form components. Hence looking to write a readable and consistent code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the code does have some redundancy, which violates the [**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself](http://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/) principle.

This could be simplified by calling `onChange()` if `allowedInput` is `false`y or if that is not the case then only when the call to the test method on it returns a `true`thy value:

```
const validatedOnChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    if (isDisabled) {
        return;
    }
    if (!allowedInput || allowedInput.test(event.target.value)) {
        onChange({ name, value: event.target.value });
    }
};
```

One could opt to take the `return` early approach, which might be more readable and decrease the indentation on the call to `onChange()` but would have an extra line:

```
    if (allowedInput && !allowedInput.test(event.target.value)) {
        return;
    }
    onChange({ name, value: event.target.value });
```

Answer (score 2):

## Simplify.

You have 3 conditions checks, `isDisabled`, "allowedInput", and `allowedInput.test`, and two effective paths, do nothing, or call `onChange`. Yet you have 2 returns statements, calls to `onChange`.

All functions will return you should try to avoid needing to add returns.

You should always avoid repeating the same code. The 2 expressions calling `onChange` need only be expressed once.

All these things will negatively impact maintenance, and readability.

### Destructure

You can also simplify the code using destructure assignment to unpack `value` from the argument `event` in the functions arguments negating the need to have the path `event.target.value` expressed 3 times.

### Short circuit

Lastly the if token is just noise and not needed as the call to `onChange` can be via a short circuit around  `&&` The right side is only executed if the left side evaluates to `true`

This gives you following

```
const validatedOnChange = ({target: {value}}) => {
  !isDisabled && (!allowedInput || allowedInput.test(value)) && onChange({name, value});
};
```